# Buggy Keyboard -Logitech k380

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth, logitech-keyboard

While all the keys work independently, some combinations (shift + key) do not work.

Also, whenever the keyboard is connected to my laptop and I have youtube running, the videos randomly pause and play in brief spurts. This issue occurs when I have my Bluetooth earphones connected. So I assumed that this might be an issue with drivers but all were up to date. Resetting the keyboard didn't help either.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I had this multiple times with different laptop keyboards. Some key combinations didn't work. The reason is how the keyboard is made up inside. A single key press triggers an electric line combination inside. If one line is broken some keys don't work anymore. I assume the keyboard is broken. Get a new one.